# Unable to get list of selected data in django rest framework

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to list of all selected items from a react application in my django backend. I do not understand what the received data format is.
here is the code:

```
def post(self,request,pk=None):
        print(request.data) //returns  <QueryDict: {'selectbut': ['service1', 'service2', 'service3'], 'selecttext': ['hello guys']}>

        for i in request.data.get("selectbut"):
             print(i) //prints only the last data in the value here it prints service3
```

I want to obtain a list with all the values of select as a list, tuple or iterator

Here is my react code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const submitform=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const formdata=new FormData(e.target)
    for (const i of formdata.values()){
      console.log(i)
    }
    axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/customer/resources/",formdata).then(
      (response)=>console.log(response)
    )
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={submitform}>
        <input type='checkbox' name="selectbut" value="service1"/>service1
        <input type='checkbox' name="selectbut" value="service2"/>service2
        <input type='checkbox' name="selectbut" value="service3"/>service3
        <input type='checkbox' name="selectbut" value="service4"/>service4
        <input type='text' name="selecttext" />service4

        <input type='submit' value="submit"></input>
        
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that FormData from the React app is URL-encoded when sent, and when Django receives it, it parses the data into a QueryDict. If you use the.get(key) method in a QueryDict, it only returns the most recent value related to the key.

To receive a list of all the values associated with the key, use the getlist() function instead of get():

```
def post(self, request, pk=None):
print(request.data)  # returns <QueryDict: {'selectbut': ['service1', 'service2', 'service3'], 'selecttext': ['hello guys']}>

for i in request.data.getlist("selectbut"):
    print(i)  # should print all the selected services
```

You may obtain a list of all the values connected to the key "selectbut" by using the syntax getlist("selectbut"). All the chosen services should print and this should function as planned.